# How to return content in entry to be printed

Tags: python, tkinter, printing, pywin32

Am trying to return the content in my entry box to be printed but the messagebox pops up even when i select the tkinter raised buttons alerting me to select the compulsory button.

Challenges:

1. when i select the compulsory button before selecting the print button the message box still pops up.
2. if i don't type in the entry widget the message for it pops up to alert me but but select button also pops up twice instead of only message box to alert me.
   have passed all the function to the print button too. My compulsory button is to be raised when it is selected then return to normal state after executing the command.

   ```
   import tkinter as tk

   from tkinter import messagebox
   import win32print, win32ui, win32con


   def output():
       global choosed

       now = new.get()

       if not choosed:
           messagebox.showerror("error", "select the buttons")
       elif len(now) == 0:
           messagebox.showerror("error", "entry empty")
       else:
          return (now)


   def accept_output():

       dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
       printername = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
       dc.CreatePrinterDC(printername)
       dc.SetMapMode(win32con.MM_TWIPS)
       scale_factor = 20
       dc.StartDoc('Win32print ')
       pen = win32ui.CreatePen(0, int(scale_factor), 0)
       dc.SelectObject(pen)
       font = win32ui.CreateFont({
           "name": "Lucida Console",
           "height": int(scale_factor * 10),
           "weight": 400,
       })
       dc.SelectObject(font)
       dc.TextOut(scale_factor * 72,-1 * scale_factor * 72, output())# to 
   receive the content in the entry widget
       dc.EndDoc()


   def raised_button(button_object):
       global choosed

       if choosed: # previously clicked
           choosed.configure(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.ACTIVE)

       choosed = button_object
       button_object.configure(relief=tk.SUNKEN, state=tk.DISABLED)


   def stop():
       global choosed

       choosed = None

       lot1.configure(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.ACTIVE)


   root = tk.Tk()
   root.geometry("400x400")


   new = tk.StringVar()
   en = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=new).pack()

   choosed = False

   lot1 = tk.Button(root, text="compulsory to select")
   lot1.configure(command=lambda button_object=lot1: 
   raised_button(button_object))
   lot1.pack(side="left")

   B=tk.Button(root, text="print number", command=lambda:[output(), stop(), 
   accept_output()])
   B.place(x=150, y=300)

   root.mainloop()
   ```

I included output() function on top of accept_output() i still got the same error.

```
   def accept_output():

    global choosed

    now = new.get()

    if not choosed:
       messagebox.showerror("error", "select one of the buttons")
    elif len(now) == 0:
       messagebox.showerror("error", "entry empty")
    else:
        return (now)  # when i add the output here it gives select button
```

welcome your suggestions to return the content in the entry widget for it be printed by selecting the compulsory button.

Comment: BTW: can't you create normal function with `output(), stop(), 
accept_output()` instead of list `[output(), stop(), 
accept_output()]` - it will be more readable for human.

Comment: i combined add output() and accept_output() it gave the same error , output() on top of accept_output() function as one function.

Comment: my sugestion doesn't resolve your problem but it made code more readable for other people.

Comment: BTW: when you do `var = Widget(...).pack(...)` then you assign `None` to `var` because `pack()/grid()/place()` return `None`. If you don't need this `var` then you can skip it and do `Widget(...).pack(...)`. If you need this `var` then you have to do it in two lines: `var = Widget(...)` and `var.pack(...)`

Comment: I don't uderstand your problem. I run code and it works as you expect. Are you sure you run the same code ? Do you run it in other program which have other `Tk()` or `mainloop()` ? BTW: I test on Linux so I have to remove `win32` module and code in `accept_output()`

Comment: the accept_output() will accept the content in the entry and print through the printer

Comment: when i select the compulsory the button still the message box pops up and return none to the printer.

Comment: instead using `outpu()` inside `accept_output()` you should in `output()` replace `else:return (now)` with `else: accept_output(now)` and use `now` inside `accept_output()`

Comment: i run the same code i posted here.

Comment: have done what you suggested i got this error TypeError: accept_output() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
so passed one argument to accept_output(*args) now giving me now not defined

Comment: you have to use `def accept_output(text): ` to receive this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do it in wrong way - you execute `output()` inside `accept_output()` so you can't stop it. You have to execute `accept_output()` in `output()` when all is OK.

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import messagebox
import win32print, win32ui, win32con


def output():
    global choosed

    text = new.get()

    if not choosed:
        messagebox.showerror("error", "select the buttons")
    elif len(text) == 0:
        messagebox.showerror("error", "entry empty")
    else:
        accept_output(text)

    choosed = None
    lot1.configure(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.ACTIVE)


def accept_output(text):

    print("printing ...", text)

    dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
    printername = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
    dc.CreatePrinterDC(printername)
    dc.SetMapMode(win32con.MM_TWIPS)
    scale_factor = 20
    dc.StartDoc('Win32print ')
    pen = win32ui.CreatePen(0, int(scale_factor), 0)
    dc.SelectObject(pen)
    font = win32ui.CreateFont({
        "name": "Lucida Console",
        "height": int(scale_factor * 10),
        "weight": 400,
    })
    dc.SelectObject(font)
    dc.TextOut(scale_factor * 72,-1 * scale_factor * 72, text) # <- text 
    dc.EndDoc()


def raised_button(button_object):
    global choosed

    # function will be not accesible if you use state=tk.DISABLED
    # so I remove state=tk.DISABLED

    if choosed: # previously clicked 
        choosed.configure(relief=tk.RAISED)
        choosed = None
    else:    
        button_object.configure(relief=tk.SUNKEN)
        choosed = button_object

# --- main ---

choosed = False

root = tk.Tk()

new = tk.StringVar()
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=new).pack()

lot1 = tk.Button(root, text="Compulsory to select")
lot1.configure(command=lambda button_object=lot1:raised_button(button_object))
lot1.pack()

tk.Button(root, text="Print number", command=output).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Instead of `Button` you could use `Checkbutton` and you will no need function `choosen` and `raised_button`. `Checkbutton` can even looks like normal button if you use `indicatoron=False`.

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import messagebox
import win32print, win32ui, win32con

def output():

    text = new.get()

    if not option1.get() and not option2.get():
        messagebox.showerror("error", "select options")
    elif len(text) == 0:
        messagebox.showerror("error", "entry empty")
    else:
        accept_output(text)

    option1.set(False)
    option2.set(False)

def accept_output(text):

    print("printing ...", text)

    dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
    printername = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
    dc.CreatePrinterDC(printername)
    dc.SetMapMode(win32con.MM_TWIPS)
    scale_factor = 20
    dc.StartDoc('Win32print ')
    pen = win32ui.CreatePen(0, int(scale_factor), 0)
    dc.SelectObject(pen)
    font = win32ui.CreateFont({
        "name": "Lucida Console",
        "height": int(scale_factor * 10),
        "weight": 400,
    })
    dc.SelectObject(font)
    dc.TextOut(scale_factor * 72,-1 * scale_factor * 72, text) # <- text 
    dc.EndDoc()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

new = tk.StringVar()
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=new).pack()

option1 = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Compulsory to select (option1)", var=option1).pack()

option2 = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Compulsory to select (option2)", var=option2, indicatoron=False).pack()

tk.Button(root, text="Print number", command=output).pack()

root.mainloop()
```